# How to access a field from a class?

Tags: java, inheritance

How can I access 'i' variable of `AA` class inside `meth3()`? I tried calling `super.i` but its just calling `i` variable of `BB` class.

```
public class SuperTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CC cc = new CC();
        cc.meth3();
    }
}

class AA {
    int i=10; // **I mean this variable to access somehow**
}

class BB extends AA{
    int i=20;

    void meth2(){
        System.out.println(super.i);
    }
}

class CC extends BB{
    int i=30;

    void meth3(){
        System.out.println(super.i);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should define a method in `AA` and not override it. You are hiding it.

Comment: try this void meth3(){
        System.out.println(super. meth2());
    }

Comment: So guyz, getter method is the only way?

Comment: @SaadKhokhar : yes, it worked, thnx!

Comment: @SaadKhokhar your answer is nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast `this` to an `AA` to read the `i` from `AA`:

```
class CC extends BB {
    int i = 30;
    void meth3() {
        System.out.println(((AA) this).i);
    }
}
```

prints

> 10

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CC cc = new CC();
        cc.meth3();

    }
}

class AA {

    int i = 10; // **I mean this variable to access somehow**
}

class BB extends AA {

    int j = 20;

}

class CC extends BB {

    int k = 30;

    void meth3() {
        System.out.println(i);
        System.out.println(j);
        System.out.println(k);

    }
}
```

Output

```
10
20
30
```

Answer (score 1):

When a class extends another class, it inherits all non-private variables from the original class.
So, let's rewrite the `BB` class to be as the compiler might see it (I'm going to write pseudo code to illustrate a point):

```
class BB extends AA{

int i = 10;//inherited from AA

int i = 20;

}
```

Now normally, if we wrote a class with two variables that both share the same name (`i` in this case) we would get a compilation error. But in the case of an extending class, any variable that shares the same name as a variable inherited from the original class is overwritten. The original `i` from class `AA` gets overwritten by the `i` from Class `BB`. This is known as name shadowing or name hiding. See this [more in depth explanation](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/what-is-variable-hiding-and-shadowing/15).

If you want to access the `AA` `i` variable from `BB` or from `CC` instances, you need to cast the object you are using to class `AA`.

Here is the test class you provided, rewritten to access the `AA` `i` variable as you asked:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CC cc = new CC();
        AA aa = (AA) cc;//cast the CC class instance to an AA instance

        aa.i;//equals 10
        cc.i;//equals 30

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about class object's between references.

anyway

Try this code

```
public class SuperTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        CC cc = new CC();
        cc.meth3();

AA aa = new AA();
System.out.println(aa.getI());

    }

}


class AA {
    int i=10; // **I mean this variable to access somehow**
public int getI() {
   return this.i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
   this.i = i ;
}
}

class BB extends AA{
    int i=20;

    void meth2(){
        System.out.println(super.i);

    }
public int getI() {
   return this.i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
   this.i = i ;
}
}

class CC extends BB{
    int i=30;

    void meth3(){
        System.out.println(super.i);

    }

public int getI() {
   return this.i;
}

public void setI(int i) {
   this.i = i ;
}
}
```

Comment: whats the need of creating again : AA aa = new AA()?? when I already created as CC cc = new CC();

Answer (score 0):

The super keyword allows you to access the variables of immediate super class... to access the 'i' value of AA class you need to call meth2() in CC class... which will print the desired vaue...